# Why is 0.86%1 not zero but 0.86 since 0.86/1 gives remainder 0?

Tags: javascript, math, modulo

If modulo(%) is same as "remainder(r)" for positive numbers then why does "0.86%1" gives "0.86" as result and not "0" since "0.86/1 = 0.86" with remainder=0.

I have seen other questions but none of them address the moduling with 1 condition. The only way I have been able to make sense of this is by thinking that 0.86 is smaller than 1 and so cannot be divided by one thus returning 0.86 as remainder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say

> "0.86/1 = 0.86" with remainder=0.

Well, only in the sense that 5/2 = 2.5 with remainder 0, and it's clear that something's wrong with that, right?

When we talk about remainders, the quotient has to be an integer. It can't be 2.5 or 0.86. If you take away as many multiples of the divisor from the dividend as you can, what's left is the remainder. For 5/2, we have

```
5-2 = 3
3-2 = 1
2>1, so we can't subtract any more, and the remainder is 1
```

For 0.86/1, we have

```
1>0.86, so we can't subtract any copies of 1 from 0.86, and the remainder is 0.86
```

Comment: **"When we talk about remainders, the quotient has to be an integer."** This was where the fault in my reasoning was. Thank You.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are not understanding Math properly.

```
 0.86
-----  =  0 Quotient & 0.86 Remainder
  1
```

This is because 1 is big enough and 1 goes 0 times in 0.86, leaving 0.86 as a remainder.

```
0.86 % 1 // This gives remainder, not the quotient.
```

So what you are looking at, is right. If you want to see what's the whole number of result, then you need to do `parseInt()`:

```
parseInt(0.86/1, 10); // This gives you 0!
```

**Better Explanation**

```js
function divide(up, down) {
  if (down == 0)
    return false;
  var res = up / down;
  var rem = up % down;
  console.log("Result (Quotient): " + parseInt(res, 10));
  console.log("Remainder:         " + rem);
}

console.log(divide(0.86, 1));
console.log(divide(7, 2))
```

Comment: You don't need the `console.log(divide(0.86, 1));`. Just call the function (`divide(0.86, 1)`). That way, you avoid the `undefined` in the console.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I noticed it. Let it be a separator. LoL. `:D` What say?

Comment: Yes, that's a new function for `undefined`!

Comment: No, I understood the math. The problem was that I assumed that doing the modulo is like an internal division done by the machine which then outputs the remainder. TIL that while it is a "sort" of division modulo cannot (doesn't?) use decimals(floats?) as a quotient, and thus works with integers as quotient only. Thank You for the help.

Comment: @Lord_Rhaziel I told the same thing right? I answered first: *If you want to see what's the whole number of result...* See?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Yes, You did, and thanks for that. However, your answer gave me the solution. It was not until I saw user2357112's answer that I had the aha moment. Nevertheless thank you again for helping me.